# Heroku Pull Resource Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

So I have tried to do Heroku db:pull and my app name, but I get the response:

```
Heroku db:pull
Resources not found
```

Answer (score 1):

usually occurs when the account you are using doesn't have collaborator permission on the app.

Comment: Exactly, it. I just did `heroku auth:logout` and then logged back in and it ran just fine. Guess I was logged into a different account.